# Изменение DOM объекта из подключаемого JS файла

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Вообщем проблемка такая, что у меня есть много элементов класса и для каждой вызывается функция передавая id объекта в js и уже там происходит некая магия, которая в конце меняет значение через inner.html:

(js файл подключен и работает).

```
<body>
  <div class = "example"> <SCRYPT> testing(id); </SCRYPT> </div>
</body>
```

В функции, в которой я, для примера, хочу изменить значение только первого элемента
пишу следующее:

```
function testing(id){
  document.get.ElementsByClassName("example")[0].innerHTML = "z.B."; 
}
```

Самое забавное что в Chrome, FireFox такой вариант работает, но вот в Opera и IE ничего не происходит.

И еще пробовал эту функцию вызывать непосредственно из html, там во всех браузерах все хорошо работет.

Как решать :3

Comment: вот тут эта тема раскрывается 
http://php-zametki.ru/javascript-laboratoriya/65-getelementsbyclassname-krossbrauzerno.html

Comment: так же не хочет работать в этих бразуерах (

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) поддерживается в IE только начиная с версии 9. В более старых версиях нужно пилить решения-polyfill, как по [ссылке](http://php-zametki.ru/javascript-laboratoriya/65-getelementsbyclassname-krossbrauzerno.html) в комментарии к вопросу или просто использовать jQuery: `$(".example").first().html(...)`

Второе, у вас необычный пример - `<script>` вложен внутри элемента, который вы собрались править. Это хороший способ нарваться на отличия в парсерах, поскольку код в `<script>` выполняется синхронно с парсингом. Лучше всего не делайте так, а если хотите поотлаживать, то хотя бы приведите полный пример, в котором проблема воспроизводится.